# product of right continuous filtrations is right-continuous?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\mathcal{G} = \sigma \lbrace G_{1},..., G_{n} \rbrace$ where $G_{1},..., G_{n}$ are subsets of $\Omega_{1}$ and $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$ is a right-continuous filtration on $\Omega_{2}$. Is $(\mathcal{G}\otimes \mathcal{F}_{t})$ right-continuous on $\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}$?

If $(\mathcal{G}_{t}) $ and $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$ are right-continuous filtrations on $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$ respectively, is there any additional hypothesis that makes $(\mathcal{G}_{t} \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t})$ right-continuous?

I ask this question because there are some articles that make this assumption. See for instance *multiperiod security markets with differential information* from Darrell Duffie and Chi-fu Huang.

For instance, in the first question, I know that $\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t} \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t+ 1/n}$. For the other side I was trying to use $\mathcal{C} = \lbrace \bigcup A \times C_{l} : A \in \mathcal{G}, \ \ C_{l} \in \mathcal{F}_{t + 1/n},  \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rbrace$ where the unions are finite. We have that $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra on $\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}$, I was trying to use monotone classes to show that it generates $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t+ 1/n} $

Comment: If $\mathcal{G}$ is finite as you write at the beginning, isn't it the case that $\mathcal{G}\otimes \mathcal{F}_{t}$ is simply a finite union  $\bigcup\limits _{G  \in \mathcal{G}} G\times \mathcal{F}_{t}$? In this case, the desired right-continuity would follow from the right-continuity of $G \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t}$ for $G  \in \mathcal{G}$.